# My Vue object is not reactive. It works locally but not on hosted server

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, axios, vue-reactivity

I get my data using axios and set my object to the new data. I also declare the object at first with empty values.

The data displays correctly in my Vue dev tools and if I log it in the console, but as soon as I display it in my HTML

```
<pre>{{myObj}}</pre>
```

It displays the old initial empty data

**My code:**

```
export default {
 data(){
  return {
   myObj: {
    foo: "",
    bar: "",
    loo: {},
    moo: [],
   }
  }
 },
 methods: {
  getData: function(){
   axios.get('/my/url')
   .then((response)=>{
     this.myObj = response.data;
     console.log("Response data: " , response.data); //**A**
     console.log("'This data:' " , this.data.purchaseorder); //**B**
   })
   .catch((error)=>{
    //ERROR
   });
  }
 }
}
```

**A:**
Displays the actual correct data from my request

**B:**
Displays the actual correct data from my request

**Things I tried:**
I read this documentation https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Change-Detection-Caveats

and I saw they said a root object can't be reactive, so I wrapped "myObj" in a container object.

```
myData: {
 myObj: {
  foo: "",
  bar: "",
  loo: {},
  moo: [],
 }
}
```

and I have replaced

```
this.myObj = response.data;
```

with

```
Vue.set(this.myData, 'myObj', response.data);
```

and

```
this.$set(this.myData, 'myObj', response.data);
```

**Nothing works!**

My main issue is that it is working perfectly on localhost! I'm guessing it has something to do with the small delay on the hosted server as opposed to local?

**UPDATE**

Here are the images with the real data

[Vue component data (from the Vue dev tools)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s0gfb.png)

[Console.log data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AGKiK.png)

[HTML displayed data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y35ZV.png)

**UPDATE 2**

As requested, an MCVE

```
<template lang="html">
<div>
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>No</th>
        <th>Product</th>
        <th>Quantity</th>
        <th>Price / mt</th>
        <th>Order Total</th>
        <th>Currency</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr v-for="(detail, idx) in purchaseorder.podetail">
        <td></td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" v-model="detail.product.product_name">
        </td>
        <td><input type="number" v-model="detail.po_qty"></td>
        <td><input type="number" v-model="detail.podetailcost.po_price"></td>
        <td><input type="number" v-bind:value="parseFloat(detail.po_qty * detail.podetailcost.po_price)"></td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" v-model="detail.podetailcost.currency.currency_description">
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data(){
    return { //Just to initialize the Obj
      purchaseorder: {
        podetail: [
        {
          po_qty: "",
          podetailcost: [
            {
              po_price: "",
              currency: {currency_id:"", currency_description:""},
            },
          ],
        }
      },

  },
  props: ['po_id'],
  methods: {
    getData(){
      axios.get('/procurement/get/editdata/'+this.po_id)
      .then((response)=>{
        this.purchaseorder = response.data;
        console.log("Response data: " , response.data); //Displays fine
        console.log("This data: " , this.purchaseorder); //Displays fine
      })
      .catch((error)=>{
        //TODO
      });
    }
  },
  mounted(){
    this.getData();
  }
}
</script>
```

[My desired result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M3Sqz.png) (This is a screenshot from my localhost, in the MCVE I removed a lot and just included the bare minimum. Don't judge the object, I did not create the DB, but I get the data in that format.

Comment: Either `getData: function(){ ... }.bind(this)` or `getData() { ... }`

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried both, neither worked. Remember, if I console.log(this.myData) it displays the data correctly (so I am guessing it sets the data correctly), but displaying it in html <pre>{{myData}}</pre> it shows the old empty data (so there is no reactivity).

Comment: You need to decide whether it is  `myData` or `myObj`. Also you cannot display an object in HTML. Have you tried  `<pre>{{ JSON.stringify(myData) }} </pre>`

Comment: Dont worry about the myData and myObj, it is the same thing, myData is just a container for myObj.

Of course I can display an object in HTML, there is no need for JSON.stringify as of Vue 2, it automatically stringifies it (please see my Update in the post)

Please note that myData and myObj is not the actual data, you'll see in the images the actual data

Comment: Have you checked on the vue dev tools? And can you create an MCVE?  http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Yes, the VUE component data image comes from the VUE dev tools

Comment: Are you sure this internal stringification is supposed to work reactively?

Comment: How do you trigger the getData method?

Comment: @connexo Please see my update that includes an MCVE

Comment: In my understanding MVCE includes ability to run the code and find the errors you're getting.

Comment: I understand, but it is inside a laravel project and I also cannot give you access to the server which produces the data. So I dont know how I can give you the ability the run the code I'm sorry. I recreated the code so that it is easy to copy and paste in a new project

Answer (score 0):

Have you call that `getData` method? It doesn't call automatically by Vue. You can use `mounted` or `created` lifecycle hooks to call that method. Somekind like this,

```
 methods: {
  getData: function(){
   axios.get('/my/url')
   .then((response)=>{
     this.myObj = response.data;
     console.log("Response data: " , response.data); //**A**
     console.log("'This data:' " , this.data.purchaseorder); //**B**
   })
   .catch((error)=>{
    //ERROR
   });
  }
 },
 mounted () {
   this.getData()
 }
```

Comment: Yes, I just showed the snippets that actually cause the problem. If you note that I say that I actually do get the data, it just doesn't set the received data to my object

Answer (score 0):

Change the `getData` method to the following, without `function`:

```
methods: {
  getData () {
    axios.get('/my/url')
     .then(response => {
       this.myObj = response.data;
       console.log("Response data: " , response.data); //**A**
       console.log("'This data:' " , this.data.purchaseorder); //**B**
     })
     .catch(error => {
       //ERROR
     });
  }
}
```

In this case, the context of `this` is bound within `getData: function () { ... }`

Comment: Thank you for the tip but still did not work. Remember it does set the data correctly (If I log it in the console I can see the correct data) but displaying it in HTML it shows the original empty data, so there is not reactivity for some reason.